# Lock An app with password

Tags: android

I would like to make an apps in android. From which i can lock other installed apps with password.
Is there any way? Please help me in coding functionality..
I can read all installed apps by following code. But i need to know how can i lock another apps?

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
    List<ApplicationInfo> installedApps = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();

    for(ApplicationInfo app : apps) {
        ApplicationInfo aa = app;
        //checks for flags; if flagged, check if updated system app
        if((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) == 1) {
            installedApps.add(app);
            Log.v("__________________",""+aa.processName.toString());

        //it's a system app, not interested
        } else if ((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {
            //Discard this one
        //in this case, it should be a user-installed app
             installedApps.add(app);
             Log.v("__________________",""+aa.processName.toString());
        } else {
            installedApps.add(app);

        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why would you lock other apps with your app ? Surely if someone wanted to access these "locked" apps, they'd just uninstall your app, use the app they want to and then reinstall your app ?? Can you please supply an example use scenario ?

Comment: Hi Richar Green, Thanks for reply. I want this thus child wouldn't access those apps.

Comment: Aha ! Ok... I'm in the same boat and I never even thought about that. I will have a think about this...

Comment: Hi Richard Green, Thanks for reply. I am searching a way for this. Do you know any way for this?

Comment: check https://github.com/amirarcane/lock-screen

Answer (score 0):

Ok - here's my proposal - you need to replace the launcher app ( see here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/vBv6RA2iPiI for a discussion about it).

That way you can then include or exclude icons of your choosing.